# Propose Fixed-Point Data Types Using an Instrumented Mex Function

Tags: matlab, function, fixed, mex

This is my matlab function:

```
function [mask] = computeMask (I, threshold, win_var, borderx, bordery)
coder.extrinsic('imfilter');
%-- compute Variances of the RGB and IR patches 
mean_I = imfilter(I,ones(win_var)/win_var/win_var,'same','symmetric','conv');
mean2_I = imfilter(I.^2,ones(win_var)/win_var/win_var,'same','symmetric','conv');
std_I= real(sqrt(mean2_I-mean_I.^2)+1e-5);
mask= std_I>threshold;
% add the border of the image to the mask 
% (filters are not complete at the border)
mask(1:((bordery-1)/2),:)=0;
mask((end-(bordery-1)/2):end,:)=0;
mask(:,1:((borderx-1)/2))=0;
mask(:,(end-(borderx-1)/2):end)=0;
% add the area where the vignetting is too strong
Cy=floor(size(mask,1)/2);
Cx=floor(size(mask,2)/2);
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:size(mask,2),1:size(mask,1));
mask(((x-Cx).^2+(y-Cy).^2)>8e4)=0;
%mask(((x-Cx).^2+(y-Cy).^2)>1.3e4)=0;
return
```

When trying to build Build "Instrumented MEX Function" I get these errors: ??* ? Expected either a logical, char, int, fi, single, or double. Found an mxArray. MxArrays are returned from calls to the MATLAB interpreter and are not supported inside expressions. They may only be used on the right-hand side of assignments and as arguments to extrinsic functions.*

Error in ==> computeMask Line: 21 Column: 18: std_I= real(sqrt(mean2_I-mean_I.^2)+1e-5);

How to fix these problems? please help me !!! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Since you declared imfilter as extrinsic, the generated code will call into MATLAB to run this function. This will result in an mXArray type. To help coder convert mxArray type to a native type you should initialize the outputs of imfilter before calling imfilter. For example, if the output of imfilter is of same type and size as its input I, then use

```
mean_I = I;
mean_I = imfilter(I,ones(win_var)/win_var/win_var,'same','symmetric','conv');
```

Note that imfilter still does not generate any code. imfilter is still called in MATLAB.

You can see documentation for this at http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/calling-matlab-functions.html in section "Converting mxArrays to Known Types".